# Using the keyword "in" with class variables and lists of class variables

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to make a 5 card poker game, and I'm trying to make a `card_draw` function that doesn't give duplicate cards, but I'm running into problems when trying to check if the randomly drawn card has already been drawn.

```
from random import choice
class standard_card:

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.card = value + ' of ' + suit

def val():
    values = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',
          '9','10','Jack','Queen','King']
    return choice(values)

def suits():
    suit = ['Spades','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds']
    return choice(suit)

def card_draw(player_hand,nogo):

    for i in range(5):
        draw = standard_card(val(),suits())
        while draw in nogo:
            draw = standard_card(val(),suits())
        player_hand.append(draw)
        nogo.append(draw)
nogo = []
player_hand = []
card_draw(player_hand,nogo)
```

So in `def card_draw()` I'm just trying to make sure that the same card is not drawn twice, which is why I have `while draw in nogo:`.

However, `while draw in nogo` is always `False`, meaning sometimes a duplicate card is put into `player_hand` and `nogo`.
I don't understand why `draw in nogo` is always `False`. For example, if I do:

```
test_card = standard_card('7','Spades')
```

and one of the cards in `nogo` generated through `card_draw()` also happens to be given the value `'7'` and `'Spades'`,

```
test_card in nogo
```

is always `False`. Could someone explain why please?

Comment: You haven't told Python how to compare one `standard_card` to another. By default objects are only equal if they're the same object, but that isn't the case. So Python can't tell when a card is already in `nogo`. You have to define the special method `__eq__` on the class in order for `in` to work.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are always creating a new object. Two Python objects are by default only the same if they are the same object.

In other words, `standard_card('2', 'Spades') == standard_card('2', 'Spades')` will return `False`.

In order for Python to know how to compare two cards for equality, you need to tell it how, by implementing the magic method `__eq__`:

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value and self.suit == other.suit

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value + ' of ' + self.suit
```

I also implemented the `__str__` method, so you can do `print(card)` and named it according to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

In the end you might want to implement a `Deck` class that holds a deck of cards. Then you can shuffle the cards and successively pop cards from the deck, guaranteeing that every card can only be drawn exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are comparing a new instance with other instances from the `nogo` list every time.

You are essentially doing this:

```
class A:
    pass

a1 = A()
a2 = A()

print(a1 == a2)
```

Which will always yield `False`